# Cannot find data type 'ntext' error in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: t-sql, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I am running a UPDATE statement against Azure SQL Data Warehouse using pyodbc:

```
cursor.execute(
  "UPDATE dbo.test SET desc = ? WHERE id = ?", desc, id
)
```

This works fine when desc value is simple. But when the value of desc is more complex (longer text), executing the above spits out the following error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]104220;
Cannot find data type 'ntext'. (100000) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I thought escaping will solve any issues but it didn't. Any idea/insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
cursor.execute(
  "UPDATE dbo.test SET desc = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) WHERE id = ?", desc, id
)
```

I guess the pyodbc is somehow converting the large string to `ntext`.

If this doesn't help, check the following [github link](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/111) - it might help you as it is explain that if:

> you're using an old SQL Server (WDAC) driver which treats nvarchar as
>   ntext and that's why you're experiencing the issue because there's no
>   reference to ntext type inside django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: I have created [an issue on GitHib](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/620) regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Update - 2022-02-21:

ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server has added a `LongAsMax` connection string parameter so we can tell the driver to map long types as the more modern `*(max)` types instead of the old `TEXT/NTEXT/IMAGE` types. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/features-of-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15#longasmax).

---

As suggested in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/620) the workaround is to use [setinputsizes](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) as a hint to the ODBC driver:

```python
# test data
desc = ' '.join(['abcde' for x in range(2000)])

crsr.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, 0), (pyodbc.SQL_INTEGER,)])
crsr.execute("UPDATE ##test SET [desc]=? WHERE id=?", desc, id)
```

That has the effect of the driver sending

```sql
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(max),@P2 int',N'UPDATE ##test SET [desc]=@P1 WHERE id=@P2',1
```

instead of

```sql
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 ntext,@P2 int',N'UPDATE ##test SET [desc]=@P1 WHERE id=@P2',1
```

Comment: This is not working when I execute a stored proc and sending params to it

Answer (score 0):

The new parameter - 'LongAsMax' in connection string that was added for ODBC Driver 18, helped me to solve similar issue.
It works for me even without using cursor.setinputsizes:

```
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={HOST};DATABASE={DB};UID={UID};PWD={PWD};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;LongAsMax=yes;'
```